# why device.multitaskingSupported not working on some devices?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multitasking

chey I am working on a ipod and i wanted to make sure that the device supports multitasking for some features to run... is there any way? I tried with this -

```
   UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
   BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
   backgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;
```

but the above function not working properly its crashing on some devices... any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are using `device.multitaskingSupported` where it is not supported... 
You should check if `multitaskingSupported` is available on device or in OS before using ..

You should do something like this  -

```
- (BOOL) isMultitaskingCapable
{
    UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
    if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
        backgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;

    return backgroundSupported;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See in the apple documentation of [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html).

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly,getter=isMultitaskingSupported) BOOL multitaskingSupported
```

**Availability**
     Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

So, `multitaskingSupported` is only available in  iOS 4.0 and later not below (3.0 or earlier).